# ggplot getting rid of panel border with axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope I'm using the correct terminology with `panel`. I have a ggplot that I want to get rid of the border between the axis and the plotting of the data:

```
 ggplot(data = diamonds %>% head(40), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()+
   theme(plot.background = element_blank()
      )
```

i.e the red section shown below, and get the axis to start where the data plots start

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, that solves it. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: No please don't! Duplicates are **good**! Increasing visibility of posts, linking different ways of asking the same question etc...